# Adding wordpress shortcodes with template file

Tags: wordpress, templates, shortcode

I'm making wordpress theme, and got stuck on page template making, so i need help...

I want my template to add shortcodes to users text edit box, when selected.
For example:
3 column home page should add:
[column1][/column1]
[column2][/column2]
[column3][/column3]

Is there a way to code this?

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-post-columns/) does exactly what you'd like, or if you'd rather write one yourself I would suggest the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page), specifically [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). The code to do what you'd like is just a little too large and complex to just slap in here and you wouldn't learn anything useful.

Comment: Tnx. I would like to write it, I'm writing whole thing from scratch and was digging through wp codex but couldn't find solution. I'll use plug in if noone gives me instruction/tutorial on how to do it.
Thanks again!